# Make a member variable object modifiable but not assignable

Tags: c++

I've searched high and low for the answer for this, perhaps I'm just not using the right terms to get any results?

Is there any way to make it so that a member variable is const in that it can't be reassigned, and will always be the same object, but still allow the object itself to be modified? Much like the behavior of a const pointer to a non-const object, but without being an actual pointer?

The main use case that I see for this would be composition. Let's say Foo has-a Bar, and you want to be able to access and modify that Bar, but not change *which* Bar Foo has. Just change the properties/call non-const methods on that Bar. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not with `const` correctness machinery; it's too primitive for that (it's just a single bit: either "change" or "not change").

You can however mark assignment private and the container a friend so that only container methods will be allowed to assign, but mutators could be marked public for others to use.

```
class Foo {
public:
    int x, y;
    Foo() : x(0), y(0) {}
    friend class Bar;
private:
    Foo& operator=(const Foo& other){
        ...
        return *this;
    }
};

class Bar {
public:
    Foo foo;
    Bar(){
        foo = Foo(); // OK from here
    };
};

void baz() {
    Bar bar;
    bar.foo.x = 42;   // Ok assigning a member of foo
    bar.foo = Foo();  // Invalid from here (doesn't compile)
}
```

Comment: An extension: You can even write a wrapper that would do that automatically for any object, something like that:
`not_assignable<int> m_integer;`

Comment: This, combined with @Shmuel H.'s wrapper suggestion is exactly what I'm looking for! Thank you.

In these situations however, is it better practice to use a getter for Foo to allow for more control in case it's ever needed, or to just make Foo public unless you're certain that you do need the extra control?

Comment: @Azk a by `non-const-reference` getter would be assignable too. Use getter that returns a new instance of not_assignable.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would just do

```
struct Foo {
    Bar bar;
};
```

Each `Foo` object then has a `Bar` subobject, which is contained within `Foo` itself, and whose address does not change. Assigning to `bar` invokes `Bar`'s assignment operator; it doesn't change the location of `bar`.

If you need polymorphic behaviour from the `Bar`, you would do

```
struct Foo {
    const std::unique_ptr<Bar> bar;
};
```

Here, since the `std::unique_ptr` is `const`, it cannot be made to point to a different `Bar` object after `Foo`'s initialization, but since the `Bar` itself is not `const`, it can be modified. You could also use `const std::shared_ptr<Bar>`.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand, but I am not sure it is has something to do with the question. The question was about not-assignable member and not about const-location member. 
In any case, the first half of your question is just not required, only assigning Bar to another Bar  will not change its address.

Comment: @ShmuelH. The question says, "... not change *which* bar Foo has." An object is still the same object when reassigned. I assume the OP misunderstands the C++ object model.

Comment: That's right, the question is confusing a little. Maybe he meant to say that assigning is like changing an object.

Comment: The question says "Much like the behavior of a const pointer to a non-const object, but without being an actual pointer?" This answer uses an actual pointer.

Comment: My apologies if the question was a confusion. Combination of bad wording and me being new to C++.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that you can make the member private and then use setter member functions that achieve the mechanics that you desire (i.e. the end user can only modify your member variables in the way that you want them to be modified).